# How to add array property value in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

How I can add array of string or int to the property value?
This is my code, but it's not working

```
   while(i<ValueArray.length)
                {               
                entityBuilder.addProperty(Property.newBuilder()
                      .setName(name))
                       .setValue(Value.newBuilder().setStringValue(ValueArray[i])));
                i++;}
```

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list value for this:

```
Value.Builder listValueBuilder = Value.newBuilder();
for (String value : values) {
  listValueBuilder.addListValue(Value.newBuilder().setStringValue(value));
}
entityBuilder.addProperty(Property.newBuilder()
    .setName(name)
    .setValue(listValueBuilder));
```

Or, using the convenience methods from `DatastoreHelper`:

```
Value.Builder[] valueArray = new Value.Builder[values.length];
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  valueArray[i] = DatastoreHelper.makeValue(values[i]);
}
entityBuilder.addProperty(
    DatastoreHelper.makeProperty(name, DatastoreHelper.makeValue(valueArray)));
```

and to retrieve the values:

```
for (Property property : entity.getPropertyList()) {
  // Find the list property by name.
  if (property.getName().equals(name)) {
    for (Value value : property.getValue().getListValueList()) {
      // Print each string value from the list value.
      System.out.println(value.getStringValue());
    }
  }
}
```

or, using `DatastoreHelper` again:

```
Map<String, Value> propertyMap = DatastoreHelper.getPropertyMap(entity);
for (Value value : propertyMap.get(name).getListValueList()) {
  // Print each string value from the list value.
  System.out.println(value.getStringValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. I've one more question, how I can get them again? I'm trying         if(entity.getProperty(i).getValue().hasStringValue()) entity.getProperty(i).getValue().getStringValue();  but it doesn't work.

Comment: By the way, I'm using your first code to set the list of values.

Comment: I added sample code to the answer. The string values are nested inside the list value.